# Error in social-engine when adding photo

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

when I am upload an image as product image... it gives an error like this

```
exception 'Engine_Image_Adapter_Exception' with message 'File " Playlist Artwork


" is not an image or does not exist' in /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Image/Adapter/Gd.php:132 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/application/modules/Sitestoreproduct/Model/Product.php(243): Engine_Image_Adapter_Gd->open(Object(Engine_Form_Element_File))
#1 /var/www/html/application/modules/Music/controllers/IndexController.php(221): Sitestoreproduct_Model_Product->setPhoto(Object(Engine_Form_Element_File))
#2 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Music_IndexController->createAction()
#3 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('createAction')
#4 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 /var/www/html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
#7 /var/www/html/application/index.php(205): Engine_Application->run()
#8 /var/www/html/index.php(24): include('/var/www/html/a...')
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the log, you have an error in the file: `application/modules/Sitestoreproduct/Model/Product.php` on the line 243. Probably the error fires on editing your music album's picture with Gd (Graphics library).

Hope this helps.